# Synchronized getter of a static final field

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, drools

I'm looking at the code fragment below and I frankly do not understand what the idea behind making this particular getter synchronized.

```
public class MVELSafeHelper {
  private static final MVELEvaluator evaluator;
  static {
    evaluator = KiePolicyHelper.isPolicyEnabled() ? new SafeMVELEvaluator() : new RawMVELEvaluator();
  }
  public static synchronized MVELEvaluator getEvaluator() {
    return evaluator;
  }
//
}
```

I'm not an expert in concurrency and I believe the people at the Drools project are far more experienced than me but I'm just wondering whether this is a typo or this construct might be worthwhile in some cases and therefore 40% of my server's CPU time isn't being spent for nothing.

Comment: You are perfectly right, there is no point in making this method synchronized.

Comment: Are there any other synchronized static methods in the class?

Comment: @vandale, nope, here is the source: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/util/MVELSafeHelper.java

Comment: @Osw If it is Drools version 6.2.0, you should alert the Drools development team.

Comment: @laune, did it already, been thinking I'm missing something, had to consult with SO community)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrency issue already been taken care by  declaring variable as final, static and there are no setter. So I don't see necessity of keeping method synchronized.

If it was about variable instantiation then since its in static block it will be executed before getter call anyway.

So you are absolutely right :)

Answer (score 0):

In this instance the synchronized keyword is not required, as the MVELEvaluator is instantiated once in a static block, and whose reference cannot be changed because it is declared final. So there's no need to control access to its reference for multiple threads.